# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I got this error when loading my secondary view (and trying to get the weight variable from the modal view controller):

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
```

This is the line highlighted by XCode (from ModalViewController.m):

```
- (CGFloat)getWeight {
    return *(weight);
}
```

But the problem is in this line of code in the viewDidAppear method (if I comment it out, it works fine) (from ViewController.m):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_showModalViewButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[modalViewController     getWeight]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

When the above line of code was in viewDidLoad it worked fine, but I need the title of the UIButton to refresh every time the secondary view appears

(I'm hoping it is a simple fix, but I am very new to iOS development)

Comment: why are you de-referencing the weight variable in your getter method?

Comment: What do you mean? I wanted to put 'return weight;', but I got an error and Xcode corrected it to '*(weight)'

Comment: what type of `weight` ?

Comment: `weight` is a CGFloat iVar declared in the ModalViewController.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of your issues is that you declared `weight` to have a type of `CGFloat *` instead of just `CGFloat`.

Change any references of `CGFloat *` to `CGFloat`.

Then change your `getWeight` method to simply do:

```
return weight;
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the two?

Comment: One if a reference to the primitive type `CGFloat` and the one with the asterisk is a pointer to a primitive type `CGFloat`. Under normal uses, you only use pointers with objects, not primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are trying to access a non-existent variable (hence the adress 0x0). Access the property within the getter via `_weight`, which refers to the ivar.

Comment: If it was a non-existent variable, it wouldn't compile. And the ivar doesn't have to be named `_weight`, it can be `weight` if that is how the property was synthesized. The OP even stated that `weight` is an ivar. No property is involved.